# Difficulty in writing Stored Proc to fetch data for Jqgrid Pagination

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, jqgrid, pagination, sql-order-by

I am using the following SQL Procedure for getting data to use for pagination in JqGrid in my web Application.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewStoredProc] 
(
    @skip int,
    @pageSize int,
    @OrderBy Varchar(20),
    @OrderByDirection Varchar(10)
 )

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @records int;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @records =(select count(*) from Data where Status='A');

    IF @skip <= 0
        SELECT TOP (@pageSize) * from Data where Status='A' 
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column1' AND @OrderByDirection='D' THEN Column1 END DESC ,CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column1' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'THEN Column1 END,
                 CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column2' AND   @OrderByDirection='D' THEN Column2 END DESC ,CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column2' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'THEN Column2 END,
                 CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column3' AND   @OrderByDirection='D' THEN Column3 END DESC ,CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column3' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'THEN Column3 END

    ELSE
        WITH GetAll AS (
           SELECT  * from Data where Status='A')
        ,GetFirst AS (
            SELECT TOP (@skip) *
            FROM GetAll
        ),GetNext AS (
            SELECT TOP (@pageSize) nt.*
            FROM GetAll AS nt
                LEFT OUTER JOIN GetFirst AS f ON f.Col1=nt.Col1
            WHERE f.Col1 IS  NULL)

        SELECT * FROM GetNext;
    RETURN @records;
END
```

Here, the Problem is i can not use `OrderBy` in WITH Clause. But, i need to get the records only after sorting.Is there any way we can do this..

Simply to say.. how to implement order by for `GetAll` data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to my that you can fix the code by usage of `OrderBy` in `GetFirst` and `GetNext` part of the WITH Clause, but **not** in the `GetAll` part. The corresponding code will be about the following

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewStoredProc] 
(
    @skip int,
    @pageSize int,
    @OrderBy Varchar(20),
    @OrderByDirection Varchar(10)
 )

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @records int;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @records =(select count(*) from Data where Status='A');

    IF @skip <= 0
        SELECT TOP (@pageSize) * from Data where Status='A' 
        ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column1' AND @OrderByDirection='D'
                      THEN Column1
                 END DESC,
                 CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column1' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'
                      THEN Column1
                 END,
                 CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column2' AND @OrderByDirection='D'
                      THEN Column2
                 END DESC,
                 CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column2' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'
                      THEN Column2
                 END,
                 CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column3' AND @OrderByDirection='D'
                      THEN Column3
                 END DESC,
                 CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column3' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'
                      THEN Column3
                 END
    ELSE
        WITH GetAll AS (
            SELECT * from Data where Status='A'
        ),GetFirst AS (
            SELECT TOP (@skip) *
            FROM GetAll
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column1' AND @OrderByDirection='D'
                          THEN Column1
                     END DESC,
                     CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column1' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'
                          THEN Column1
                     END,
                     CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column2' AND @OrderByDirection='D'
                          THEN Column2
                     END DESC,
                     CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column2' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'
                          THEN Column2
                     END,
                     CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column3' AND @OrderByDirection='D'
                          THEN Column3
                     END DESC,
                     CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column3' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'
                          THEN Column3
                     END
        ),GetNext AS (
            SELECT TOP (@pageSize) nt.*
            FROM GetAll AS nt
                LEFT OUTER JOIN GetFirst AS f ON f.Col1=nt.Col1
            WHERE f.Col1 IS  NULL
            ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column1' AND @OrderByDirection='D'
                          THEN nt.Column1
                     END DESC,
                     CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column1' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'
                          THEN nt.Column1
                     END,
                     CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column2' AND @OrderByDirection='D'
                          THEN nt.Column2
                     END DESC,
                     CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column2' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'
                          THEN nt.Column2
                     END,
                     CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column3' AND @OrderByDirection='D'
                          THEN nt.Column3
                     END DESC,
                     CASE WHEN @OrderBy='Column3' AND @OrderByDirection !='D'
                          THEN nt.Column3
                     END
        )  
        SELECT * FROM GetNext

    RETURN @records;
END
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg..Once again..:)